# One Piece Episode 533 Music Name at 19:47

Tags: one-piece, music

What is the music name...that plays in episode 533 at 19:47 min when Brooke runs to see Mermaid Princess

Comment: Are you sure in 19:47? because I watched it and it's the scene when Zoro comes and blocks and attack from the King.

Answer (score 1):

This song from One Piece Movie 9 is called **The Doctor Living in Castle (Dr no Sumu Shiro)**. Here's the [Crunchyroll episode link](http://www.crunchyroll.com/one-piece/episode-533-its-an-emergency-the-ryugu-palace-is-occupied-657953) and [YouTube song link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PebtVuAJWXw) for reference.

Comment: I have removed the link to the illegal steam site. in futrure please refer to [this list](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587) for legal sites to link to